# codeignite file_get_contens not working when angularjs variable through file path is send

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

`$scope.formatfilename = response.filename[0].filepath;`//Itcontains my filepath e.g. http://localhost:8080/abc/myfloder/ab.html

`$filename1 ='{{formatfilename}}';` // I accessing above path in codeIgniter view. When I echo this variable it has the file path also

```
echo file_get_contents($filename1);
```

It gives me file not found error. but If, I pass static url to file_get_contents() method that time it gives the result.
any solution ??

Comment: Try too access file url (value of $filename) in browser, is it found ?

Comment: It is found in  browser

Answer (score 0):

maybe typo error. should be `$filename1`

```
echo file_get_contents($filename1);
```